# "Deployment Orderer to Docker"

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, wsl-2

My docker-compose.yml file for fabric-orderer deployment:

```
fabric-orderer:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    container_name: fabric-orderer1
    environment: 
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=file
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPFILE=/mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/genesis-blocks/genesis1.block
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/organizations/ordererOrgs/orderer1/msp
        - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=orderer1MSP
    command: orderer
    ports:
        - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./genesis.block:/mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/genesis-blocks/genesis1.block
```

I always receive next error:

```
fabric-orderer1 | 2021-07-02 10:38:03.671 UTC [orderer.common.server] loadLocalMSP -> PANI 003 Failed to get local msp config: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/organizations/ordererOrgs/orderer1/msp/signcerts: stat /mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/organizations/ordererOrgs/orderer1/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory

fabric-orderer1 | panic: Failed to get local msp config: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/organizations/ordererOrgs/orderer1/msp/signcerts: stat /mnt/b/Desktop/HFForMastersWork/organizations/ordererOrgs/orderer1/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory
```

But I checked all paths and all of them correct. Help me, please. Where is my error?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a file on your host machine from inside the container, which doesn't work. You need to mount the file into your container so you can access it.

Comment: Did you write any of the application code here yourself, or are you just trying to deploy a pre-built image using Compose?

Comment: @DavidMaze  I understood that I can built Fabric Network using applicaion code or using shell commands with bin files from "fabric-samples". While I try to built and deploy my network using Compose.